# ModPagespeed – Proxy Publisher Failure TIMEOUT

Tags: proxy, mod-pagespeed

There's a certain website I visit repeatedly. Sometimes everything's okay, but from time to time I get the following error message while loading the page:

`Fetching of original content failed with the following error: Proxy Publisher Failure TIMEOUT. If you own this domain, please consult this FAQ.`

where "FAQ" is linked to http://code.google.com/speed/pss/faq.html#publisherfailure

At the same time, the URI rewrites 'itself' to `http://domain.com/?ModPagespeed=noscript`

I only encountered this issue on my Mac, but not on my windows machine. Why's that?
I'm using a direct connection – no proxy at all.

What is causing this issue? Is it a plugin in Firefox on my Mac? But why does it happen whith Chrome as well? Problem with my ISP? Or is it the server and a misconfigured apache module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a broken origin server, which is (intermittently) failing to return a response to the PageSpeed Service proxy. This shouldn't have to do anything with your browser or operating system - if you can prove otherwise, that would be *really* interesting...

Long story short: should ping the site owner to notify them that their server is intermittently failing.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not worth much but when I started using Google page speed I occasionally get the same error. But when I change my server settings back to how they where the problem goes away. But I guess that's what I get for trying something very much still in testing.

When consulting the "faq" provided by Google it says:

This error occurs when PSS cannot fetch content from your origin server due to one of the following reasons.

```
TIMEOUT: Connection from PSS server to the origin server timed out.
CLOSED: Origin server closed the connection.
DISCONNECTED: The origin server disconnected the connection to PSS server.
CONNECTION_ERROR: PSS server could not connect to the origin server.
```

Note that some of these errors may be transient errors served by your hosting provider. Please contact your hosting provider to fix the situation appropriately.

Unfortunately it seems to me Google not wanting to accept responsibility for there service not being up to scratch. I could be wrong but that's my penny's worth :)